# specify which tab a programatically generated picture box will go in

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to programatically generate pictureboxes in my application, however Im using a tab control for my application so I can have multiple pages.

I was wondering how I can define which tab the picturebox can go in? and if i can get it on the write tab how do I insert it into my flow control?

Below is the code im using when a picturebox is created:

```
private void AddPictureBox(string IP, Bitmap image)
{
    PictureBox pbs = new PictureBox();
    pbs.Image = image;
    pbs.Tag = IP;
    pbs.Height = 169;
    pbs.Width = 289;
    pbs.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pbs.Visible = true;

    boxes.Add(pbs);
}
```

Im also trying to add the pictureboxes inside a flow control so I dont worry about adding a location of the image.

However when the code runs No pictureboxes are being created, or if they're being created they're behind the tab control therefore I can't see them.

ANY help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is 'boxes'?

Comment: sorry I should have specified, boxes is List that contains all the boxes created, to access the last created picturebox i use boxes.last

Comment: Where are you adding them to your TabControl/FlowControl? Please add all relevant code to the question in the form of a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, a new PictureBox will not display on a form until you add it to the Controls collection of a Control that already exists on the form (or the form itself).

Comment: @AndyG Im not an experienced programmer, this is the first time i've ever tried to create pictureboxes through code, How do I add it to a list of controls?

Comment: Everything visible on a form, including the form itself, is a Control. Each control has a Controls collection, and an Add method to add to this collection, making a new control visible. If this means nothing to you then it is apparent that you should start with a few basic tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a reference we need to add the PictureBox to the tabcontrol:

```
private void AddPictureBox(string IP, Bitmap image) {
    PictureBox pbs = new PictureBox();
    pbs.Image = image;
    pbs.Tag = IP;
    pbs.Height = 169;
    pbs.Width = 289;
    pbs.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pbs.Visible = true;

    tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(pbs); //This will display picturebox inside the Tab control with an id : tabControl1
    boxes.Add(pbs); 
}
```